# jQuery / Ajax content replacement

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a problem i want to solve this problem.

1. when click on link fade actually content out
2. delay and load new content
3. simply show new content not fade in

This is my solution but its absolutely troubling... it seems that the content when its load and fade in this process 2-6 times one after another and on the last time it shows correctly.. when i click on another navigation point it loads the new content 2-6 times, too.

Sry for my english hope you can understand it.

Whats wrong there?

```
$(function() {
  $('.activator').click(function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.hash = target;
    $.ajax({
    url: target,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#contentreplace')
            .fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $(this).html(data).show();
            });
    }
});
return false;
});
});
```

I have no idea how I can solve that :/

Comment: please make a jsfiddle.

Comment: i cant make a fiddle because its a ajax thing... when i look in the firebug the opacity is going up down up down up down ... and finally it displays correctly

Comment: did your try to replace your content in the `done()` function instead of `success` ?